# Warning after submitting sitemap to Google: "We found that some URLs redirect to other locations"

Tags: sitemap, search-engine-indexing

I noticed that I have three warnings when I submitted my Sitemap. They all say this:

> When we tested a sample of URLs from your Sitemap, we found that some
>   URLs redirect to other locations. We recommend that your Sitemap
>   contain URLs that point to the final destination (the redirect target)
>   instead of redirecting to another URL.

I'd like to try and resolve this issues but I'm not sure what to do.

Sitemap url for reference: http://www.teacupsandtulips.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: That message looks pretty self-explanatory to me.  Which URLs from your sitemap have this message?

Answer (score 3):

Your XML sitemap is a signal to search engines that these are the most important pages on your site and you'd like them indexed. Thus, you don't want to introduce confusion into the process by including outdated URL's, which may get indexed instead of your intended ones. (Plus, crawlers don't like being made to work harder than they have to.)

You'll have to find those redirected URL's and swap the old URL's out for the new ones in the sitemap. No URL in your sitemap should send the crawlers to a different page.

The problem URL's can be as obvious as an outdated URL or as seemingly innocuous (but they're actually harmful) as the lack of a trailing "s" in http or a "www" where there isn't one.

In addition to Google Search Console or Bing Webmaster Tools, you can use software like Moz or a Chrome add-on like Check My Links to find these redirects. If your site is small enough, you can also manually eyeball your sitemap, paying attention to small differences. (And in some cases, you may need to flush your server cache or even rebuild your sitemap before resubmitting.)