# Should an XML sitemap include redirecting URLs?

Tags: redirects, xml-sitemap

Should I include URLs that redirect in my site's XML sitemap?

If page X is permanently redirected to page Z, would I include the page X, or only page Z?

Comment: I edited "robots sitemap" out of your question.   There is no such thing.  Maybe you were thinking of "robots.txt" which is a separate file and not very related to sitemaps.

Comment: See also: [Warning after submitting sitemap to Google: “We found that some URLs redirect to other locations”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115819/warning-after-submitting-sitemap-to-google-we-found-that-some-urls-redirect-to)